# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException

Tags: json, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am facing such an error in my application. I guess the problem is due to having char in `note_title` and `note_desc`. I couldn't find the solution. Is there anyone who can help?

[navgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5tZf.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6zEs.png)

[NoteDetailScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqmzE.png)

[notes entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VijHU.png)

[? and other char cause error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSrND.png)

I tried change `note_title` and `note_desc` types but didnt work.

Comment: The error describes an unterminated string, that means that the contents that you are trying to deserialize probably include a `"` character in a field that isn't being escaped properly. Could you include the code calling the navigation to the details screen?

Comment: Thanks for comment i tried parcelize data and it work. I will share the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way;

Let’s say you have a class like this:

```
@Parcalize
@Entity(tableName = "NOTES")
data class Notes(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo("note_id") @NotNull var note_id:Int,
    @ColumnInfo("note_title") @NotNull var note_title: String,
    @ColumnInfo("note_desc") @NotNull var note_desc: String,
    @ColumnInfo("note_date") @Nullable var note_date: String?
): Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readString().toString(),
        parcel.readString().toString(),
        parcel.readString()
    ) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(note_id)
        parcel.writeString(note_title)
        parcel.writeString(note_desc)
        parcel.writeString(note_date)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Notes> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Notes {
            return Notes(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Notes?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}

annotation class Parcalize
```

You can define the NavType like this:

```
class NavTypo : NavType<Notes>(isNullableAllowed = false) {
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): Notes? {
        return bundle.getParcelable(key)
    }

    override fun parseValue(value: String): Notes {
        return Gson().fromJson(value, Notes::class.java)
    }

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: Notes) {
        bundle.putParcelable(key, value)
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
composable(
            "note_details_page/{note_id}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("note_id"){
                    type = NavTypo()
                }
            )
        ){
            val note = it.arguments?.getParcelable<Notes>("note_id")

            if (note != null) {
                NoteDetailScreen(note, navController)
            }
        }




Card(
     backgroundColor = choosedColor,
     modifier = Modifier
                .padding(3.dp)
                .sizeIn(maxHeight = 250.dp)
                .combinedClickable(onClick={

            val note = allNotes.value!![it]

            val noteJson = Uri.encode(Gson().toJson(note))

                                                    
     navController.navigate("note_details_page/${noteJson}")
```

}